# Pandas Dataframe dictionary of list values to merged rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {'Manchester United' : [[2021-04-26, 2], [2021-04-28, 1]], 'Chelsea' : [[2021-04-26, 1], [2021-04-28, 0]], 'Liverpool' : [[2021-04-26, 0], [2021-04-28, 2], [2021-05-02, 1]]}
```

With Pandas Dataframe I would like to do the following:

[image]

How it can be achived?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with pd.DataFrame constructor:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v, columns = ['Date','Score'], index=[k]*len(v)) for k,v in my_dict.items()])
```

Output:

```
                         Date  Score
Manchester United  2021-04-26      2
Manchester United  2021-04-28      1
Chelsea            2021-04-26      1
Chelsea            2021-04-28      0
Liverpool          2021-04-26      0
Liverpool          2021-04-28      2
Liverpool          2021-05-02      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) + [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), as follows:

```
df = pd.Series(my_dict).explode().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Team', 'Date', 'Score']
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

                Team        Date  Score
0  Manchester United  2021-04-26      2
1  Manchester United  2021-04-28      1
2            Chelsea  2021-04-26      1
3            Chelsea  2021-04-28      0
4          Liverpool  2021-04-26      0
5          Liverpool  2021-04-28      2
6          Liverpool  2021-05-02      1
```

**Source Data**

Corrected the source data to make it work:  modified date in numeric expression (e.g. 2021-04-06 i.e. 2021 - 04 - 06) to string '2021-04-06':

```
my_dict = {'Manchester United' : [['2021-04-26', 2], ['2021-04-28', 1]], 'Chelsea' : [['2021-04-26', 1], ['2021-04-28', 0]], 'Liverpool' : [['2021-04-26', 0], ['2021-04-28', 2], ['2021-05-02', 1]]}
```